# Telegram-bot menu

Tags: javascript, node.js

Столкнулся с проблемой, при создании телеграм бота- в меню можно записывать только системные команды, а заказчик просит сделать нечто подобное[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Отсюда вопрос друзья, подскажите как это можно реализовать вместе со стикерами , на js (пример на картинке)?

Comment: Просто вставляешь unicode смайла в текстовое поле . Пример:  Карты.

Comment: а меню то как сделать?

Comment: Почти в каждом туториале есть как добавлять кнопки. Я просто делал своего на java, поэтому примера кода у меня под рукой нет. Это называется replykeyboardmarkup. Вот тут есть пример: https://morioh.com/p/ed516194c8db